# Sign extend 11 bits to 32 bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, sign-extension

How do you sign extend an 11 bit number to a 32 bit number in C++?

I have the following function, but it is not returning the proper sign-extension as expected:

```
unsigned int signExtend11to32ui(int i) {
    int mask = 2047; // 0x7FF or 0000 0111 1111 1111
    return static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<int>(i & mask));
}
```

The following function works correctly for sign-extension of 16 bits to 32 bits:

```
unsigned int signExtend16to32ui(short i) {
    return static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<int>(i));
}
```

Comment: What does it return and what do you expect? Any small example?

Answer (score 2):

Since right and left shifts are arithmetic in C++, you can right shift you integer up to most significant bit of int and then back:

```
std::int32_t i = 2047;
i = (i << 21) >> 21;
```

this puts -1 to `i`

Comment: This might pass the tests, but the result of shifting into the sign bit or right-shifting a negative value is not well-defined.

Comment: @BoPersson Could you elaborate more on right-shifting not being well defined?

Comment: @ErikP. - The C++14 standard says: *"The value of `E1 >> E2` is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. [...] If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."* So it might, or might not, work depending on what system you are using. You have to read the compiler manual to see what it is doing.